# Can Voodoo dolls be moved?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

In one of the haunts (25/26?) the traitor has hidden several Voodoo dolls about the house. When we played I had the dog and found my fellow explorers doll. I tried to use the dog to move it (to take it to the other player) but we eventually reasoned that the rules don't say anything about moving the dolls (they aren't items that can be picked up, stolen etc), so even I couldn't have moved them.

Were we right, or could I have collected the dolls whilst the other explorer tied up the traitor?

Answer (score 4):

From a strict reading of the [rules](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_SurvivalRev_120105.pdf), I would say no. Presumably, the dolls still do damage to you until they are destroyed. It wouldn't make much sense if you could remove them from their [precarious positions](http://www.wizards.com/avalonhill/rules/BHH_TraitorRev_120105.pdf) and still take damage.

> Then you must **find the dolls in the room** and destroy them.
>
> Once you find a doll, you can automatically destroy it if it corresponds to you. You can find the location of any doll, but you can only safely destroy your own doll.